# Is 'strategy.opentrades.profit' working now in pinescript of Tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

Is 'strategy.opentrades.profit' working now in pinescript of Tradingview??

If I use the variable then the below error comes up.
: Undeclared identifier 'strategy.opentrades.profit'

I think every 'strategy.opentrades.' variable series is not working...

Could you test one time for me?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried and worked.

The codes are directly taken from tradingview pinscript documentation page

```
// Returns the profit of the last open trade.
//@version=5
strategy("`strategy.opentrades.profit` Example 1", commission_type = strategy.commission.percent, commission_value = 0.1)

// Strategy calls to enter long trades every 15 bars and exit long trades every 20 bars.
if bar_index % 15 == 0
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if bar_index % 20 == 0
    strategy.close("Long")

plot(strategy.opentrades.profit(strategy.opentrades - 1), "Profit of the latest open trade")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I really appreciate it!! you are really helpful thanks